# why is this imagepng not working?

Tags: php, gd, odoo

image_small.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$id = (isset($_GET['im'])) ? $_GET['im'] : 0;

//fetch the image from database
$query='SELECT image_small FROM hr_employee WHERE id='.$id;
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

$raw = pg_fetch_row ( $result ,0)
$img=$raw['image_small'];

header("Content-Type: image/png");

if( !file_exists($cachefile) ) {
    imagepng($img, $cachefile);
    imagedestroy($img);
}

$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'rb');
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

I get the following error:

imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: it seems header("Content-Type: image/png"); doesn't works as expected. Can you remove this line and see if other chars occurs?

Comment: Are you sure that GD is activated ?

Comment: Yes, GD is activated acording to phpinfo()

Comment: Be aware of the SQL injection your example offers! Filter `$_GET[im]` before inserting it into your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very explicit, [imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) expects a resource. To be simple, imagine a resource as an object from which you cant't know the class. In fact, GD is developped in C language, and PHP wraps all *unknown* C structures inside resources.

So, you need to ask GD to create this resource for you, before using gd-family functions. If you stored your image raw, you'll get it raw and will need to use [imagecreatefromstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) function.

```
$gdh = imagecreatefromstring($img);
imagepng($gdh, $cachefile);
```

Comment: Bytea format isn't raw binary? I guess it is, and you'll need simply use `imagecreatefromstring` function on it. Something like: `$gdh = imagecreatefromstring($raw['image_small']);` and then pass `$gdh` to `imagepng` function.

Comment: I did it. It is not working. I will post the output in a few.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as if your database contains base64 encoded image data.

Try Changing your code to

```
$img = base64_decode($raw['image_small']);
```

and see whether the output changes.